# Sending reading sensor as massage to sink node

Tags: c, simulation, contiki

I'm working in `upd-sink.c` and `udp-sender.c` examples of `contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-collect` path in Cooja. I want the sender mote to send their sensor data to sink. In `udp-sender.c` code, there is a `struct` called `msg` and this `struct` has a data field called `msg` that is of type `struct collect_view_data_msg` type. I want to put my reading sensor in msg and send to sink.How do i do this? I have a program for sensing temperature. I want to send `s` variable as massage to sink. I want to just simulate this network in Cooja.

The sensor program:

```
PROCESS(sensor_acq_process,"Sensor Acquisition");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&sensor_acq_process);
PROCESS_THREAD(sensor_acq_process,ev,data)
{ 
  static struct etimer et;
  static int val;
  static float s = 0;
  static int dec;
  static float frac;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  printf("Starting Sensor Example.\n");

  while(1)
  {
   etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND * 2);
   SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);

   PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

   val = sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);
   if(val != -1) 
   {
     s = ((0.01*val) - 39.60);
     dec = s;
     frac = s - dec;
     printf("\nTemperature=%d.%02u C (%d)\n", dec, (unsigned int)(frac * 100),val);               
    }       

    etimer_reset(&et);
    SENSORS_DEACTIVATE(light_sensor);
    SENSORS_DEACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
  } //end of while

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Function `collect-common-send` of `udp-sender.c` program:

```
 void collect_common_send(void)
{
  static uint8_t seqno;
  struct {
    uint8_t seqno;
    uint8_t for_alignment;
    struct collect_view_data_msg msg;
  } msg;
  /* struct collect_neighbor *n; */
  uint16_t parent_etx;
  uint16_t rtmetric;
  uint16_t num_neighbors;
  uint16_t beacon_interval;
  rpl_parent_t *preferred_parent;
  linkaddr_t parent;
  rpl_dag_t *dag;
  if(client_conn == NULL) {
    /* Not setup yet */
    return;
  }
  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  seqno++;
  if(seqno == 0) {
    /* Wrap to 128 to identify restarts */
    seqno = 128;
  }
  msg.seqno = seqno;

  linkaddr_copy(&parent, &linkaddr_null);
  parent_etx = 0;

  /* Let's suppose we have only one instance */
  dag = rpl_get_any_dag();
  if(dag != NULL) {
    preferred_parent = dag->preferred_parent;
    if(preferred_parent != NULL) {
      uip_ds6_nbr_t *nbr;
      nbr = uip_ds6_nbr_lookup(rpl_get_parent_ipaddr(preferred_parent));
      if(nbr != NULL) {
        /* Use parts of the IPv6 address as the parent address, in reversed byte order. */
        parent.u8[LINKADDR_SIZE - 1] = nbr->ipaddr.u8[sizeof(uip_ipaddr_t) - 2];
        parent.u8[LINKADDR_SIZE - 2] = nbr->ipaddr.u8[sizeof(uip_ipaddr_t) - 1];
        parent_etx = rpl_get_parent_rank((uip_lladdr_t *) uip_ds6_nbr_get_ll(nbr)) / 2;
      }
    }
    rtmetric = dag->rank;
    beacon_interval = (uint16_t) ((2L << dag->instance->dio_intcurrent) / 1000);
    num_neighbors = uip_ds6_nbr_num();
  } 
  else {
    rtmetric = 0;
    beacon_interval = 0;
    num_neighbors = 0;
  }

  /* num_neighbors = collect_neighbor_list_num(&tc.neighbor_list); */
  collect_view_construct_message(&msg.msg, &parent,
      parent_etx, rtmetric,
      num_neighbors, beacon_interval);
  //i add this code but it led to an error:invalid type argument
  //of'->'(have 'struct collect_view_data_msg')

  SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
  msg.msg->sensors[TEMP_SENSOR] = sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);
  //end added

  uip_udp_packet_sendto(client_conn, &msg, sizeof(msg),
      &server_ipaddr, UIP_HTONS(UDP_SERVER_PORT));

  SENSORS_DEACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which platform for you use in Cooja? (Most likely `sky`.)

1. The sensor readings are already included in the collect view message if the platform is `sky`. If it's not, the collect view code under `apps/collect-view/` can be easily extended do do that using `collect-view-template.c` as the base.
2. Don't use [floating point numbers on embedded systems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/905928/2435820).
3. If you really really know what you are doing, want to use floating point, and want to have data in ASCII format, create new field in the `struct collect_view_data_msg` that is a `char` array, and `snprintf` the value of the sensor in that field.

As a minor comment, this code is not needed:

```
SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
msg.msg->sensors[TEMP_SENSOR] = sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);
...
SENSORS_DEACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
```

As mentioned, the `sht11_sensor` is already read and included in the message in the collect view app.

Comment: I use sky platform.You mean i add a char array field in `struct collect-view-data-msg` for example `char buf[100]` and put value of sensor in it this way: msg.`mag->buf=sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);` ?

Comment: And if that piece code is not needed, where i activate and deactivate sensor?

Comment: See the function `collect_view_arch_read_sensors` in `collect-view/collect-view-sky.c` - the sensor is already activated there.

Comment: `msg->buf=sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);` is not even going to compile. In C, to change the value of an array, a loop, `memcpy()` or `str[n]cpy()` must be used`. Please read an intro to C.