# passing char and float value to a string

Tags: c, pic

I need to send a get request using a string, and so I need to pass a float and a char value to the string in order to send it.Im trying to connect a PIC18F4550 to wifi using a ESP8266 module I also need to read and write into a database. I have been using this function I made to send AT Commands and its been working fine :

```
void send (char dato[]){
    int i = 0;
    while (dato[i]!=0){
        TXREG=dato[i];
        i++;
        while(TRMT==0);
    }
    TXREG = 0x0D; 
    while(TRMT==0);
    TXREG = 0x0A;
}
```

The problem I have is that i need to send :

```
send("GET /ESPic/index3.php?temp=temp&luz=luz");
```

But luz is char and temp is float.Using a FTDI232 and Arduino IDE I am reading the data between the PIC and the ESP8266.I dont really know how to do what I need.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Where is `luz` and `temp` in your code?

Comment: Can you build the message string with `sprintf` before transmitting it? Aside, the code is missing an initial or final status check.

Comment: Note that you might have to enable the `printf` function family in the cross-compiler. Also please see [Using floats with sprintf() in embedded C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905928/using-floats-with-sprintf-in-embedded-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `float` to a *string* first.

---

When sending a textual version of `float`, best to use avoid `"%f"` and use `"%e"`, `"%g"`, or `"%a"` with enough precision.

`"%f"` can be very long for large numbers.  It coverts to an uninformative +/- `"0.000000"` for about half of all `float` (the small ones).

These 3 formats `e,g,a` have better control on the maximum length and easier to insure  the needed precision is used.

```
float temp;
char luz;
// send("GET /ESPic/index3.php?temp=temp&luz=luz");

#define SEND_FC_FMT "GET /ESPic/index3.php?temp=%.*e&luz=%c"
//                     -   d   .    ddd...ddd            e   - d...d \0 
#define FLT_ESTR_SIZE (1 + 1 + 1 + (FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1) + 1 + 1 + 5 + 1)
char buffer[sizeof SEND_FC_FMT + FLT_ESTR_SIZE];

sprintf(buffer, SEND_FC_FMT, FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, temp, luz);
send (buffer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumimg your platform supports `sprintf`, you probably want this:

```
float temp;
char luz;
...
char buffer[200];
sprintf(buffer, "GET /ESPic/index3.php?temp=%f&luz=%c", temp, luz);
send(buffer);
```

Comment: If temp has a 37.5 value and luz a 0 value, what would be the buffer´s length? I need it  for the `send("AT+CIPSEND=AA")` in which AA is the length

Comment: Use strlen(buffer) to get the length of the buffer.  In your CIPSEND=AA, is AA always 2 characters with leading zero if necessary?  Note that leading zero in C means octal.

Comment: The buffer will be NUL terminated. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.